# Authorization: user rights vs service rights

Tags: rest, authentication, service, architecture, authorization

I have a REST API that uses JWT for authenticating clients of 2 types:
- users through a web application
- services

Each client has its own rights (e.g. one can access resource 1 but not resource 2 using the API).

Now a service can have a UI and the problem I'm facing is that I don't really know which rights should the API consider when a request is sent by a service through a user action from the service UI: service rights? User rights? The intersection of both?

For example, let's say the API provides a list of products through ˋGET /products`, that list can be restricted by client's rights:
- user U can list product1, product2.
- service S can list product2, product3.
What products should be listed for user U from the UI of service S?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're asking, you should be thinking about the intersection of users and services. There's no such thing as "service rights" or "user rights" in the absence of the other. Instead, there are rules dictating which users can access which services.

Typically any REST call is processed on the server by first identifying the user and verifying the user can access this service, then performing the actual service if verified.

Comment: Thank you for your help, actually I am considering the case when the user can access the service, but they have different accesses to resources. I added an example to make it more clear!